# NodeJs/MongoDB - Wait X amount of time before user can Post/Submit again

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a Video Rating site where users can submit their videoes, but I want to avoid users from submitting/spamming with their videoes and limit them to submit once every hour or something. Whats the best way to do that? I'v been reading about SetTimeOut/Interval and also about using some middlewares but no luck yet.

**After this code is posted/requested by a user, I want to give them a timeout/cooldown**

```
router.post('/submit', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next){
   User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function (err, userfound){
           var video = new Video({
             title : req.body.title,
             videoLink : req.body.videoLink,
             category : req.body.category,
             ownByUser : req.user._id,
           });

           video.save(function (err, moreVideo){
                   userfound.myFrags.push(moreVideo); //Error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
                   userfound.save();
           });
           res.redirect('/dashboard')
   });
```

});

I am also saving the time/date of when the posts was submitted, maybe I should use that and compare it to the current date? Any help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: I'd recommend checking the most recently submitted video by that user and doing a time comparison. Otherwise, maybe using a session variable

Answer (score 1):

This might sound weird but you can have a different collection called 'lapse' for the purpose with a TTL index of 1 hour on createdDate, Whenever user submits a video first check that there is a document for that userId in the collection lapse.

If there is no such document then save the video and make an entry with the userId and createdDate in the lapse collection.

If there is already a document then tell the user that he is still in cooldown period.

This will work in the sense that TTL index deletes the document by itself after the set time in this case 1 hour.

With this you can also extend the feature like you allow only 2 videos in an hour duration or so by maintaining a counter.

Downside is you might need to have a fail safe like what happens if it saved the video but failed to make an entry into lapse collection?

More about [TTL Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to use server check by having a middleware, something like below middleware. I have not tested it, but you can try it as it or with some modifications,

```
function limitVideo (req, res, next) {
 Video.findOne({
      ownByUser : <userId>,
 },
 {
      createdDate : 1
 }
 )
 .sort({createdDate : -1})
 .exec (function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
           return <Ur Err msg>
      }
      if(!data) {
           return <Ur Err msg>
      } else {
           var ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000; // in ms
           var lastPostdate = data.createdDate;
           if(((new Date) - lastPostdate) >= ONE_HOUR) {
                next();
           } else {
                return <You cant upload videos>
           }
      }
 })
}

// Use middleware in ur post route
router.post('/submit', isLoggedIn, limitVideo, function (req, res, next){
<Ur code>
});
```